# How to "smartly" translate formulas into form of natural language?

Tags: android, c++, nlp

I am recently working on a project aiming at evaluating whether an android app crashes or not. The evaluation process is:

1. Collect the logs(which record the execution process of an app).
2. Generate formulas to predict the result (formulas is generated by GP)
3. Evaluate the logs by formulas

Now I can produce formulas, but for convenience for users, I want to translate formulas into form of natural language and tell users why crash happened.(I think it looks like "inverse natural language processing".)

To explain the idea more clearly, imagine you got a formula like this:

```
  155 - count(onKeyDown) >= 148
```

It's obvious that if count(onKeyDown) > 7, the result of "155 - count(onKeyDown) >= 148" is false, so the log contains more than 7 onKeyDown event would be predicted "Failed".

I want to show users that if onKeyDown event appears more than 7 times(155-148=7), this app will crash.

However, the real formula is much more complicated, such as:

```
(< !( ( SUM( {Att[17]}, Event[5]) <= MAX( {Att[7]}, Att[0] >= Att[11]) OR SUM( {Att[17]}, Event[5]) > MIN( {Att[12]}, 734 > Att[19]) ) OR count(Event[5]) != 1 ) > (< count(Att[4] = Att[3]) >= count(702 != Att[8]) + 348 / SUM( {Att[13]}, 641 < Att[12]) mod 587 - SUM( {Att[13]}, Att[10] < Att[15]) mod MAX( {Att[13]}, Event[2]) + 384 > count(Event[10]) != 1))
```

I tried to implement this function by C++, but it's quite difficult, [here's the snippet of code](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~b98901160/question/printNatural.cpp) I am working right now.

Does anyone knows how to implement this function quickly?(maybe by some tools or research findings?)Any idea is welcomed :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found an empty file at your snippet of code link.

Comment: It sounds like your are looking to implement an instance of [_natural language generation_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_generation), which in many ways is the inverse of _parsing_, but a part of NLP. If there is a great variety of possible predicates and actions in your formulas, this is going to be extremely complex.

Comment: If you can explain in simple natural language why I have an appendix, then you can explain in simple natural language what a GP-generated formula is actually testing ;-)

Comment: Thanks jogojapan!I think I got something to study.

Comment: Sorry Steve I didn't catch the point.Can you explain it further?

Comment: Don't even try it. Generate the messages properly so you can just use the normal format strings with placeholders or similar stuff. Don't try to "smartly" interpret stuff; you'll be spending an "infinite" amount of time to pretty-print messages that only have the purpose of making the developer fix the program so the message no longer appears...

Comment: If I misunderstand your words, plz tell me :) 

Since I can't predict how many execution steps should be considered,so I use GP system to "guess" why error happened.The GP system only takes simple function set and combine them genetically so that the messages are quite complicated.

But that's a good point!I should spend some time trying to avoid this interpret stuff...

Comment: @Ricky: I'm mostly joking, but what I mean is that evolution in general (and in particular both human evolution and GP) can create things that work in very non-obvious ways. So your GP formulae might well end up having some sub-clauses that it's incredibly difficult to explain in English *at all*, let alone using machine-generated English. Of course you could translate the sequence of symbols 1-1 into some English words that mean the same thing "it is not the case that either the sum of the eighteenth element of Att and the ...", but that doesn't help readability much.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh I understand now. But I think I can improve them to a point better than now, although my progress now truly doesn't help readability.Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just try to simplify the formula and print it in a formulaic way anyway.   for example, 155 - count(onKeyDown) >= 148 simplifies to count(onKeyDown) > 7 in your example.